# Bypassing Validation rule by fields?

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I Have a scenario we have one field "start date".
Whenever the start date has passed the seven days we cannot edit this field.
But we can edit other fields in the record if we even pass the seven days. Now whenever am trying to edit and update the record with other fields it is showing me the above validation and I'm unable to save.
How can i achieve this please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding ISCHANGED(Start date) into you formula. This way the validation rule only runs if the Start Date is changed and when 7 days from Start date had passed, if that's your only requirement.

So it will look like below:
AND(ISCHANGED(Start date), your existing formula to validate 7 days from Start date)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion I'm unable to add this ISCHANGED(Start_Date__c <TODAY()-7 ). Error: Incorrect argument type for function 'ISCHANGED()'.

Comment: Make sure you use something like `ISCHANGED(Start_Date__c)` if your field has the API name Start_Date__c.

Comment: @PhilW thanks for ur reply, What if i consider today's date if system.today start date is past 7 days i need to restrict the startdate from editing. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use TODAY in formulas and validation rules. Take a look at the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5).